# Random MAC address flag location in bluetooth packet?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, packet, pcap, mac-address

I am analysing `.pcap` files containing Bluetooth traffic.

I am trying to find a flag that is set which ensures that the Bluetooth MAC address of a device is random and/or changes.

I have seen parts of the packets such as this:

```
.0.. .... = Randomized Tx Address: False
```

But haven't been able to find much more information on what this does.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BR/EDR can only use IEEE-allocated device addresses, they are called "public" addresses. LE introduced another class of addresses, "random" addresses. They are both 48-bit. LE can use both, see [Vol 6, Part B, 1.3](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=421043).

In the space of random addresses, there is another subdivision in three groups:

- static addresses (non-IEEE allocated address, not guaranteed to be unique, but statistically non-colliding),
- non-resolvable private addresses (ephemeral address you cannot identify a device with),
- resolvable private addresses (ephemeral address that can identify a device only for people that have access to a key called IRK).

This enables the privacy features of BLE.

In places where a device address is used in LE, there is always a one-bit field accompagnying a device address for specifying whether address is to be interpreted as a "public" or a "random" address.

Your expert from wireshark seems to come from a LE advertisement packet header, see [Vol 6, Part B, 2.3](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=421043) for packet details.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a specific part where it talks about the 'Randomized Tx Address' flag?

Comment: Actual flag bit is "Random address" in spec, not "Randomized address". Looks like Wireshark guys had it wrong. Random addresses are what I described above.